# bash script to remove date folders by folder name

Tags: bash

I have a script which creates folders in a backup folder by the current date. This script is run once a day, every day via cron.

Is there a way to remove the folders older than 3 days via folder name? something like

date -3 ?

Script that works: Thank you to Jo So. This script creates a folder by date. Compresses the files for backup, sticks them in your backup directory and clears out backups older than 3 days :-)

```
    #!/bin/bash

    cd /home/backups

    mkdir $(date +%Y-%m-%d)

    cd /opt/

    tar -pczf /home/backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/opt.tar.gz code

    cd /var/

    tar -pczf /home/backups/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)/var.tar.gz work

cd /home/backups/
threedaysago=`date -d "3 days ago" +%Y%m%d`

for backup in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
do
    backupdate=`echo "$backup" | tr -d -`   # remove dashes

    if test "$backupdate" -lt "$threedaysago"
    then
        rm -rf "$backup"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
threedaysago=`date -d "3 days ago" +%Y%m%d`

for backup in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]
do
    backupdate=`echo "$backup" | tr -d -`   # remove dashes

    if test "$backupdate" -lt "$threedaysago"
    then
        rm -rf "$backup"
    fi
done
```

Work independently of mtime, and I can tell you that it will not break under particularly strange corner cases ;-)

Comment: This is Awsome. Thank you. This works Very Well. I have Amended my script above should anyone wish to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Removes daily backups (of type "regular file") older than 3 days:

```
rm -f `find $YOUR_BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +3`
```

From `find` man page:

> ```
>    -mtime n
>           File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
>           for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
>           of file modification times.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Is there anyway to do it so as not to use date modified, but rather folder name, since the folders are named by date?

Comment: will you have a case where you will modify a folder with already created backup?

Comment: Your script will break and will delete arbitrary files when the directory contains files with strange filenames. Also, relying on mtime is **very** brittle, I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: I will agree with you if you elaborate more on the "strange filenames" and describe the weak points in more detail. I don't say it's the best solution, but the format of the filenames is exactly known, because you define them in the backup script.

Comment: The problem is that you `find ...` which will return all files. An attacker or accident could insert a file named `"name_of_a_file_you_want_to_keep<whitespace>name_of_another_file_you_want_to_keep<whitespace>..."`. `rm -f` will then happily remove all the files with the filenames in the original filename because it doesn't know that they were in fact coming from a single filename, but split up to multiple filenames by the shell.

Comment: I see your point (+1), but the find will not return ALL files - only those older than 3 days (you want to delete those anyway). And considering the scenario, that you have an attacker who can write in your backup directory, I suppose worse things will happen than having to deal with "strangely crafted filenames".

Comment: That might be true. But there's always the possibility that you insert files with whitespace yourself (accident or unknowingly about script), and why doing it incorrectly when doing it correctly is no trouble?