# In linux shell, How to cp/rm files by time?

Tags: linux, shell, time, cp, rm

In linux shell, When I run

```
ls -al -t
```

that show the time of files.

How to cp/rm files by time? just like copy all the files that created today or yesterday. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/q/11448885/1007273 should be helpful

Comment: @herbertD : Note that the time your `ls` shows is the **modification** time, not the creation time. Look at the `find` command, in particular to the options `-mtime` and `-newer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple Example

```
find /path/to/folder/ -mtime 1 -exec rm {} \; // Deletes all Files modified yesterday
```

For more examples google for bash find time  [or take a look here](http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/find.php)

Comment: Thanks! I use find * -mtime 0 to get today's file.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on what you actually want to do, `find` provides `-[acm]time` options for finding files by accessed, created or modified dates, along with `-newer` and `-min`. You can combine them with `-exec` to copy, delete, or whatever you want to do. For example:

`find -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 -type f -exec cp '{}' backup \;`

Will copy all the regular files in the current directory more than 1 day old to the directory `backup` (assuming the directory `backup` exists).